# Assembly - How OS knows the size of program and variables from COM file before loading it?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I read that the com file contains the instructions only, so how OS knows the size of program and variables from COM file before loading it?
Also how CPU identify the variables?

Comment: A COM program can contain data, code, and a stack. All of that information is contained within a single 64k segment. COM programs use the tiny memory model where CS=DS=SS

Comment: The CPU doesn't even try to identify "variables" in the high-level-language sense.  All it does is run instructions, some of which load from and store to memory.  The set of rules for how this works is called the ISA (Instruction Set Architecture).

Answer (score 4):

In the case of MSDOS, it doesn't know the size, so it allocates all of the available memory for the .COM program. If the .COM program is going to terminate and stay resident, it can release the memory that it doesn't need before exiting.

Comment: @AhmadNaoum It copies the entire contents of the .COM file into memory, byte for byte. Any variables in the file are copied into memory. Note that strictly speaking variables are high-level language concept. As far the CPU and MS-DOS are concerned they don't really exist. They're just bytes in memory. Neither the CPU nor MS-DOS knows their names, their type or where in memory they're located.

Comment: The OS knows the size of the file, so it knows how many bytes to copy into memory when loading the program.

Comment: @PeterCordes - .COM file images may not include uninitialized data (depending on tool set), and do not include the stack.